# Cockpit docker compose and docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cockpit

I need to create a custom docker image with Cockpit and ubuntu.
But I can't start the service and expose it once it has been installed.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Australia/Brisbane

RUN apt-get update -qq -y && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y curl net-tools && \
    apt-get install -y cockpit


EXPOSE 9090

CMD [ "command to run and expose cockpit" ]
```

**I tried with**:

```
service cockpit.socket start && tail -f /dev/null

# And
service cockpit start && tail -f /dev/null
```

Error: Service not found: cockpit.socket

**And also with**:

```
CMD [ "cockpit" ]
```

Error: Command not found

Also it seems I can't use `systemctl` in a docker Image.